# Can I update my iPhone 4S on iOS 6 to iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, upgrade, ios

I have new iPhone 4S with iOS 6.1.0. Can I upgrade my current iOS version to 8.0.2?

Whether there can be a problem that I skipped iOS 7 and jump straight from 6 to 8 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There won't be a problem.

I'm not 100% sure that upgrading to iOS 8 will be in your best interest, though, because I've seen lots of reports of people with 4Ss having performance problems on iOS 8.

Comment: Thanks! I'm interesting in iOS 8 because there are many apps, that won't work on my iOS 6. And update to official iOS 7 is passed, so the way is only to update to iOS8 (change to iPhone 5 I'm not considering options)

Comment: if you rather have IOS 7 which I recommend (iphone 4s iOS 8 user here) you can check http://www.ipswdownloader.com and download the instal file you want

Comment: @dennismuys It's cool, but I do not trust none-official resources :(

Comment: As stated above; you definitely do not want to do that.  My wife did with her 4s, and it degraded performance to barely usable.  If you can score IOS 7, that actually will offer a huge performance and increase, and it's a hell of a lot more attractive ( at least to my tastes ).